# Excel Power Query - prevent adding prefixes to data cells and column names

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Excel Power Query, and it is adding characters to my data (Highlighted in yellow in the attached image). 
I am going to Data > Get Data > from file > from workbook
and selecting a .xlsx file. some files work with no problems. Others, have the following:

The yellow portions are things that Excel has added. Is this a known issue and how do I fix it? For the column, it should be "Active/Inactive". The MEDHOK_ID has some "-" in it, and the ECD is nothing but numbers.

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing an example of the source data, and your M code.

Comment: Those are escaped UNICODE for your characters: 002F is /, 0031is 1, and 0032 is 2. Something is causing the characters to be escaped, which displays _x, the UNICODE, and _. There is a known issue with PowerApps, where having spaces or special characters in certain data sources' column names causes this. I don't know if this helps, but here's a [link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/x0020/m-p/54227#M22450) about that.

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time. You can do one-by-one replacements of "_x0030_" with "0", "_x0031_" with "1" etc;  My versions are usually all numerical (_x0030_ to _x0039_) and I don't use the "_" character, so I do it in two steps by replacing "_x003" with a null then "_" with a null and that gets all of them. If you also are finding "_x0020_" (a space) you'd have to do something more fancy